# How to compare two drop down values and make button for comparing work in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, button, drop-down-menu

I am beginner in visual studio and I heaven't found the answer on this yet.

Well, I have two drop down lists. Each of them has 7 values. I want compare each value from first drop down with each value from second drop down and the reasult must show in a special label.

For example, if I choose "2" from first drop down and "3" from second drop down list, in a special label must appear "5" as an reasult. How can I do that?

Also, I'd like to add a button which will compare two listed values.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly im not sure if i've understood your question right
For that: if in one combobox is one value in second another it would be something like that u have to add new event to both.
and it will look something like that:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result = 0;
        result = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem) + Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
    }
```

For each of them, you can add also some ifs to check values and as well catching exceptions.
If u would like to ADD values after button click - u should simply ignore above code and add button and then add event for onClick (simply double click button on your form)
with similar code inside.